# How do I get the centre item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Of the items currently displayed on-screen within a `RecyclerView`, is there any way to obtain the `View` id of the one in the centre?

For example, if there are five items currently displayed, give me the id for the 3rd one.

Comment: I think i know what you are asking, but could you post your code? Have you tried using Log.i(); to see what is happening in your onClick method?

Comment: Thank you for the help @mr-concolato, but yigit's question gives me the answer I was looking for!